# "[name path=]" causes document to not finish compiling

Tags: pgfplots, errors, fillbetween

I want to plot the area between two functions. On one machine it compiles nicely, on the other one it hangs.

Code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots, fillbetween}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} % \begin{axis} gave a warning
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{groupplot}

\nextgroupplot

\addplot 
%[name path=curve1]
coordinates { (0,0) (1,0) };

\addplot
%[name path=curve2] 
coordinates { (0,1) (1,1) };

%\addplot[blue!5] fill between[of=curve1 and curve2];

\end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Adding any of the `[name path=]` options causes the code to not finish compiling (even when written in just one line). Adding `\tracingall` shows the following self-repeating output in the `.log` file:

```
\pgfplots@name@path@cmd@pgf@two@ten #1\pgfeov ->\let \tikz@intersect@def =\gdef \pgfplots@name@path@cmd@pgf@two@ten {#1}
\pgfeov 
#1<-curve1
{\let}
```

According to `\pgfversion`, the version is 2.10, and the editor used is TeXnicCenter 2 with pdflatex (if that's relevant). The error does not occur when I use `\begin{axis}` instead of a `\begin{groupplot}`, but since I want to plot the whole thing together with other graphs, this does not solve my problem.

Is there anything I have overseen for correct usage, or is it some problem with the pgf version?

Comment: I am at 3.0.0 and it is fine.

Comment: As Symbol 1 said, your code works fine with `pgf` v3 (specifically 3.0.1a) and `pgfplots` v1.13. So it appears that it is a version problem. Therefore I'm voting to close.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem appears to have been fixed in a newer version of pgf and/or pgfplots.